# Is lexically_normal() redundant on a call to std::filesystem::canonical() or std::filesystem::weakly_canonical()?

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

Would there be a reason to call lexically_normal in either of these cases:

```
std::filesystem::path filepath = someFuntionThatGetsAPath();

filepath = std::filesystem::canonical (filepath).lexically_normal ();
filepath = std::filesystem::weakly_canonical (filepath).lexically_normal ();
```

I'm seeing this in a code base and I am not sure if it is necessary. I am assuming that canonical and weakly canonical doesn't fail and returns a normalized path already.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like redundant but implementations had flaws (and were affected by changes of standard)

Answer (score 1):

From the reference for [weakly_canonical](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical):

> ... The resulting path is in normal form.

So there is no point in calling `lexically_normal` on the return value of this function.

However, for `canonical`, the resulting path is not necessarily in normal form, and so it makes sense to call `lexically_normal` on the result.

Comment: This is what I had thought as well. It's confusing that canonical wouldn't be in normal form but weakly_canonical would.

Comment: In what aspects would something be canonical but not normal?

Comment: @michig54 I have no idea *why* actually. It just seems to be specified that way, at least as far as the reference I linked to says,